# URLSave and bitbucket

Tags: web-access

I'm trying to download a file hosted on bitbucket via Mathematica. The direct link

https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/downloads/FIRE5.2.tar.gz

works fine with Firefox and wget. However, with URLSave all I get

```
URLSave["https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/downloads/FIRE5.\
2.tar.gz", CreateTemporary[]]
```

is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIVFPT2YJYYZY3H4A</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>GET

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
1477322781
/bbuseruploads/fdfbb5c6-4342-4621-9823-cc913478e72e/downloads/75ffeb5e-e570-4a10-9467-d687c3062f32/FIRE5.2.tar.gz?response-content-disposition=attachment; filename="FIRE5.2.tar.gz"&amp;versionId=null</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>Pyu902sDRDMeufUigiM0vDMXJ5c=</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>47 45 54 0a 0a 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 63 6f 64 65 64 0a 31 34 37 37 33 32 32 37 38 31 0a 2f 62 62 75 73 65 72 75 70 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 66 64 66 62 62 35 63 36 2d 34 33 34 32 2d 34 36 32 31 2d 39 38 32 33 2d 63 63 39 31 33 34 37 38 65 37 32 65 2f 64 6f 77 6e 6c 6f 61 64 73 2f 37 35 66 66 65 62 35 65 2d 65 35 37 30 2d 34 61 31 30 2d 39 34 36 37 2d 64 36 38 37 63 33 30 36 32 66 33 32 2f 46 49 52 45 35 2e 32 2e 74 61 72 2e 67 7a 3f 72 65 73 70 6f 6e 73 65 2d 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 64 69 73 70 6f 73 69 74 69 6f 6e 3d 61 74 74 61 63 68 6d 65 6e 74 3b 20 66 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d 65 3d 22 46 49 52 45 35 2e 32 2e 74 61 72 2e 67 7a 22 26 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 49 64 3d 6e 75 6c 6c</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>039E898261C2178A</RequestId><HostId>96DrO0eeLTSKdX19gOTLP1qP+LbHzcyLZjq6N9zyGjb5fp1fkvbqIqlWPVXqvG1AFBJETdrABBs=</HostId></Error>%
```

I also tried

```
URLSave[URLFetch[
   "https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/downloads/FIRE5.2.tar.\
gz", "Headers"] /. {___, {"Location", s_}, ___} :> s, 
 CreateTemporary[]]
```

but this leads to the same result. I see that the file is apparently hosted on Amazon AWS and this seems to be the issue, but given my limited knowledge of Web programming I don't see a way to fix it. Is there some one-line magic to make the download work?

Ideally I would be interested in a solution that works on Mathematica 8 to 11.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm not the owner of the repository and I have no AWS account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default `"Content-Type"` header used by *Mathematica* is confusing Amazon. Setting it manually to empty string works for me:

```
URLSave["https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/downloads/FIRE5.2.tar.gz",
    "Headers" -> {"Content-Type" -> ""}
]
(* "/tmp/74feaab0-90f3-4540-9e3e-054b87b8e60f.tmp" *)
```

where file with returned path is proper archive file containing FIRE.

---

> Ideally I would be interested in a solution that works on Mathematica 8 to 11.

`URLSave` was introduced in version 9.0. `FetchURL` from `` Utilities`URLTools` `` works in all versions from 8 to 11:

```
Needs["Utilities`URLTools`"]
FetchURL["https://bitbucket.org/feynmanIntegrals/fire/downloads/FIRE5.2.tar.gz",
    FileFilters -> {}, "RequestHeaderFields" -> {"Content-Type" -> ""}
]
(* "/tmp/Temp30809___FIRE5.2.tar.gz" *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the perfect solution to my problem.